# Regular Expression E-Mail (Java)

Tags: java, regex, email

I know there are a lot of questions about regular expression and e-mail combined. But it's always about a "simple" e-mail format, for e.g. `any_mail@domain.com`

As we can read on many websites, developer hide emails for those standard regex on a "simple trick". The hide the `@` behind `(at) or [at]`.

So i am looking around here for a regex considering the case of `(at) or [at]` in an e-mail.

I am already testing stuff like this:

```
[a-zA-Z0-9_\\.-]+(@|[[(]at[)]])[a-zA-Z0-9-_\\.]+\\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}+
```

The key point is the `@` or `(at)` or `[at]` part!

I would appreciate to any solution :)

EDIT:: I want this regex to find e-mails written like `any_mail(at)domain.com`

Comment: `[[(]at[)]]` what do you think `[..]` does?

Comment: [ [ ( ] -> [ or ( 
at -> at
[ ) ] ] -> ) or ]

Comment: Nope, `[` and `]` are special characters in character sets, which can be used to create inner character sets. For instance `[a-z&&[^c-f]]` will create intersection of `[a-z]` and `[^c-f]`. In other words `[(]` in `[[(]]` represents only `(`, not `[` or `(` or `]`. You should use Bohemians solution which is very clear and easy to change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The regex fragment matches any of:

- `@`
- `[at]`
- `(at)`

with optional spaces around the term:

```
" *(@|\\(at\\)|\\[at\\]) *"
```

Answer (score 1):

`(@|[\\[\\(]at[\\)\\]])`

Actually, this will match `abc(at]example.com`.